# C# DateTime Format yyyy-MM-dddd

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I want to get back to the format I gave it, but it did not change. The web service works only in this format.

Instant="2016-12-26T08:20:37.494+03:00"

```
DateTime fDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);

req.AP_Info.Instant = fDate;
```

I wrote the above codes, but I get an error.
The language of my computer is Turkish.

*The format I want*:   2016-12-26

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime is a type that represents dates and times but a DateTime object itself has has no specific output format. 
You can indeed display a date represented by a DateTime in a variety of output formats by calling the ToString() method on it but it is important to note that that this doesn't change any format of the actual DateTime object. It just creates a string representation of the date using the specified format.

If you have a string that represents a yyyy-MM-dd date you could convert it to a DateTime using the DateTime.ParseExact method like this:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime fDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as the IFormatProvider makes sure that it will work regardless of the current thread's culture settings.

But if the type of your Instant property is DateTime rather than String you don't need to care about the format because a DateTime property can only be set to a DateTime object and a DateTime object has no specific format.

Comment: https://s23.postimg.org/42m2730x7/datetime.png
Thank you so much for your reply.I will take care of the web service.There is a result like the picture.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime.ToString(`) method:

```
DateTime fDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);
string myformatted = fDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I want it to return DateTime.It's not String.

Comment: DateTime fDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);
The codes I wrote above made a mistake.